# Hetzner - not booting after installimage script, 1 SSD + 2 HDD

Tags: linux, hetzner

I got a problem, with installing installimage on 1 SDD and leaving 2 HDD for future RAID.
After clean installimage, server is not responding. Only rescue bring it back to live.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to force grub install on all drives.
After installimage, you need to change root directory to fresh installation, and run grub-install on all disks.

```
root@rescue ~ # installimage

#  Assuming /SDC is SDD
# set->SWRAID 0, Comment DISK[n], ensue DISK1 is on SDD

root@rescue ~ # mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt/
root@rescue ~ # mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/boot/

root@rescue ~ # cfdisk /dev/sda
# delete all. create single partition.primary. write. quit.
root@rescue ~ # cfdisk /dev/sdb
# delete all. create single partition.primary. write. quit.

root@rescue ~ # cd /mnt/

# set all proc/sys/dev avaliable from fresh install mount
root@rescue /mnt # mount -t proc /proc proc/
root@rescue /mnt # mount --rbind /sys sys/
root@rescue /mnt # mount --rbind /dev dev/

# https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=descriptions-chroot-change-root-directory-execution-command
root@rescue /mnt # chroot /mnt/

root@Ubuntu-1212 / # grub-install /dev/sdc
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@Ubuntu-1212 / # grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@Ubuntu-1212 / # grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@Ubuntu-1212 / #  exit
root@rescue ~ # reboot
```

ps. I deliberately leaving comments and shell info, because you need to understand what each command do.

Comment: Why is this the solution though?